# Distribution of $X$ uniform on $(-A,A)$ if $A$ is uniform on $(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, bayes-theorem

> Suppose that the random variable $X$ is uniformly distributed symmetrically around zero, but in such a way that the parameter is uniform on $(0,1)$; that is, suppose that
>   $$X\mid A=a \in U (-a,a),\qquad A \in U (0,1)$$
>   Find the distribution of $X$.

This is my approach:

$$F_{X}(x)=P(X\leq x)=\int_{\Re}P (X\leq x \mid A=a)\cdot f_{A}(a)\cdot da=\int_{0}^{1}P (X\leq x \mid A=a)\cdot da$$

Next, I determine $P (X\leq x \mid A=a)$ and got the following:

$$P (X\leq x \mid A=a)=  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & x\leq -a \\
      \frac{x+a}{2a} & -a\leq x\leq a \\
      1 & a\leq x \\
\end{array} 
\right. $$

It is from here on that I have problems. I don't know how to properly think about the support of $a$ when evaluating $$\int_{0}^{1}P (X\leq x \mid A=a)\cdot da.$$

Comment: Why not use the standardest Bayes formula $$f_X(x)=\int_\mathbb R f_{X\mid A}(x\mid a)f_A(a)da=\int_0^1\frac1{2a}\mathbf 1_{|x|<a}da=\mathbf 1_{|x|<1}\int_{|x|}^1\frac{da}{a}=-\log|x|\,\mathbf 1_{|x|<1}\ ?$$

Comment: That simplifies it indeed,  but still my problem is that i do not understand how you go from the 3rd step to the 4th.

Comment: Apart from the fact that I lost a factor $2$ and that the two last expressions should read $$\frac12\mathbf 1_{|x|<1}\int_{|x|}^1\frac{da}a=-\frac12\log |x|\,\mathbf 1_{|x|<1}$$ you mean? :-) Well, if $|x|>1$ the $a$-integral from $0$ to $1$ restricted to $a>|x|$ reduces to $0$ since the interval where one should integrate reduces to the empty set And if $|x|<1$, this $a$-interval is $(|x|,1)$, hence the formula.

Comment: Ok thanks alot i get it now